# How to check that a Cassandra node is ready?

Tags: cassandra

I have a Cassandra node running in a Docker container and I want to launch a CQL script when the database is ready. I tried checking the port to detect when it's ready :

```
while ! nc -z localhost 7199; do
    sleep 1
done
echo "Cassandra is ready"
cqlsh -f ./createTables.cql
```

But the port is opened before the database is really ready, and the `cqlsh` therefore fails. How to properly check the Cassandra status and launch the script ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you need to wait on another port: 9042. This is the port that is used by CQLSH.

Another approach could be also waiting for execution of `cqlsh` instead of `nc` (or as a second step, because `nc` is much faster to execute).  For example, you can use something like these commands:

```
while ! cqlsh -e 'describe cluster' ; do
    sleep 1
done
```

to wait until Cassandra is ready...

Comment: This line will appear in the cassandra system.log `Starting listening for CQL clients on /0.0.0.0:9042...` when the node is ready.

Comment: It's not recommended to listen on 0.0.0.0

Comment: Do you have any ideas for when cqlsh is not installed? I need to do this check from another container and installing is not an option. nc keeps giving me empty results... 9042 is also opened before cassandra is ready.

Comment: @QuintenScheppermans did you ever find a solution without cqlsh?

Comment: You can look into logs, to see that startup is complete, or use `nc -z 9042`...

Comment: @Juan, for seedcontainers used for testing we use wait-for-it (https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it). For java services that connect to it, me made them retry connection until available as microservices should be able to live independently of eachother.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shell command to poll [`nodetool status`](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/troubleshooting/use_nodetool.html#nodetool-status) on your Docker container, and wait until the node/s are marked as `UN`.

For example, let's say you only have 1 Cassandra node in a Docker container and it's named `cassandra-node-1` (set with [`docker run --name`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#name---name)), the output of `nodetool status` if `cassandra-node-1` is already available is:

```
$ docker exec cassandra-node-1 nodetool status
Datacenter: my-datacenter-1
=======================================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load      Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack 
UN  172.21.0.2  7.91 MiB  16      100.0%            c74fb450-fe49-4a73-9a0b-f25fbc4ad096  rack1
```

where `UN` means the node is `Up` and `Normal`.

Then an `until` bash loop can be:

```bash
until $(docker exec cassandra-node-1 nodetool status | grep "UN" > /dev/null); do 
  echo "Waiting for cassandra-node-1..."; 
  sleep 1; 
done
```

where we `grep` for a `UN` string. `grep` will return a non-zero exit code if there is no matching string and [`until`](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_03.html) will keep looping while the condition is false-y. (If you have multiple nodes, you'll need to do a better check that all the nodes are `UN`. This is just an example for the case of 1 node.)

The sample output would be:

```
$ until $(docker exec cassandra-node-1 nodetool status | grep "UN" > /dev/null); do echo "Waiting for cassandra-node-1"; sleep 1; done;
Error response from daemon: Container 42103912deea0329e5a2e73eda7a7a157f757598a58dc79e9ec9972ae95ec7a8 is not running
Error response from daemon: Container 42103912deea0329e5a2e73eda7a7a157f757598a58dc79e9ec9972ae95ec7a8 is not running
Error response from daemon: Container 42103912deea0329e5a2e73eda7a7a157f757598a58dc79e9ec9972ae95ec7a8 is not running
Waiting for cassandra-node-1
Waiting for cassandra-node-1
$
```

where the `until` loop exits once the node is `UN`.

You can also try to use other `nodetool` commands like `info` and `describecluster`:
https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/tools/nodetool/nodetool.html