# How to check if docker Cassandra instance is ready to take connections

Tags: bash, spring-boot, docker, cassandra

I have two docker instances that I launch with docker-compose.
One holds a Cassandra instance
One holds a Spring Boot application that tries to connect to that application.

However, the Spring Boot application will always fail, because it's trying to connect to a Cassandra instance that is not ready yet to take connections.

I have tried:

- Using restart:always in Docker-compose

  - This still doesn't always work, because the Cassandra might be up 'enough' to no longer crash the Spring Boot application, but not up 'enough' to have successfully created the Table/Column family. On top of that, this is a very hacky solution.
- Using healthcheck

  - It seems like healthcheck in compose doesn't have restart capabilities
- Using a bash script as entrypoint

  - In the hope that I could use netstat,ping,... whatever to determine that readiness state of Cassandra

Right now the only thing that really works is using that same bash script and sleep the process for x seconds, then start the jar. This is even more hacky...

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check that Cassandra is ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034869/how-to-check-that-cassandra-is-ready)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the spring boot service defined in the docker-compose.yml **depends_on** the cassandara service? If yes then the service is started only if the cassandra service is ready.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on

Take a look at this github repository, to find a healthcheck for the cassandra service.

https://github.com/docker-library/healthcheck

### CONCLUSION

After some discussion we found out that docker-compose seems not to provide a functionality for waiting until services are up and healthy, such as Kubernetes and Openshift provide (See comments below). They recommend to use wrapper script (docker-entrypoint.sh) which waits for the depending service to come up, which make binaries necessary, the actual service shouldn't use such as the cassandra client binary. Additionally the service depending on cassandra could never get up if cassandra doesn't, which shouldn't happen.

A main thing with microservices is that they have to be resilient for failures and are not supposed to die or not to come up if a depending service is currently not available or **unexpectedly** disappears. Therefore the microservice should be implemented in a way so that it retries to get connection after startup or an **unexpected** disappearance. **Unexpected** is a word actually wrongly used in this context, because you should always expect such issues in a distributed environment, and even with docker-compose you will face issues like that as discussed in this topic.

The following link points to a tutorial which helped to integrate cassandra properly into a spring boot application. It provides a way to implement the retrieval of a cassandra connection with a retry behavior, therefore the service is resilient to a non existing cassandra database and will not fail to start anymore. Hope this helps others as well.

https://dzone.com/articles/containerising-a-spring-data-cassandra-application

Comment: Depends_on doesn't work as it only affects build order, not run order. Your other comment might actually save me! I'll report back later today :)

Comment: The doc of **depends_on** says it defines the startup order of services when **docker-compose up** is executed, and if only a single service is started, then all its depended services and their depended services and so on are started as well, before the actual services is started

Comment: Yes, startup of the container, it unfortunately doesn't take the start-up of cassandra into account.

Comment: Ok, i assumed that docker-compose depends_on would wait for the service to become healthy. I have just found out that docker-compose previous to version 3 had a condition service_healthy option, they have removed from depends_on. Maybe this helps https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/. Long story short, a wrapper script has to wait before starting the service.

Comment: Yeah, which is why your second option seemed like a good idea at first. But now I remember that cqlsh is not installed on the other docker container. It's not an option to do so, so I'm back to 0 :(

Comment: Then how about implementing your spring boot service in a way it does retry to get the cassandra connection, instead of failing if it isn't present the first time it tries to connect? Retry is a good approach for a microservice, so you get rid of the direct service dependencies, whereby a service fails to start because another service is currently unavailable. What happens if the cassandra service is up and then disappears unexpectedly, which is not an uncommon use case? Can your service recover from that, or will it die?

Comment: I think that in the end that will be the best solution. So for anyone interested after this, I will most likely try to implement [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/containerising-a-spring-data-cassandra-application)

Comment: That's a very good approach, and will make your service resilient to failures, which it has to be if it should work properly in an distributed service environment, where you have to handle such issues all the time. Service are not supposed to die and not coming up just because depending service are currently not available. This is the microservice world. Maybe take a look at the microprofile specifications as well, especially the microprofile-fault-tolerance specification https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-fault-tolerance

Comment: I managed to get it working with the link I provided, perhaps add that to your conclusion and I will accept your answer as the solution. Thank you for your insights.

Comment: @ThomasHerzog one important thing here when implementing this logic is that in production scenarios like in kubernetes, you want your microservices to fail if they can't reach a desired state, and automatically retry until that state is reached. Implementing your server with extra logic may keep the container running "normally" infinitely, without reporting an error, which is not what you really want. IMO for development is OK to build scripts to start and wait for dependencies, but I would leave the server's code without implementing a block of code to wait for another svc