# How to perform healthcheck on a cassandra DB dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, cassandra

So I need to create a Docker Image of cassandra that have keyspace. So i made this docker file

```
FROM cassandra

WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY script.cql ./script.cql
COPY entrypoint-wrap.sh  ./entrypoint-wrap.sh

CMD ["cassandra", "-f"]
RUN bash entrypoint-wrap.sh
```

and script.cql contains

```
CREATE KEYSPACE project WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3};
```

and i want to run this script

```
#!/bin/bash

 echo "checkcqlsh"
program=no
while  [ $program = no ]
  do 
  if ! [ -x "$(command -v cqlsh)" ]; then
  echo 'Error: cqlsh is not included.'
  program=no
  else 
  program=yes
  cqlsh -f script.cql 
  fi
done
```

But when it check `if` condition  the image building stops because of an error that DB didn't have started yet. How to check if the cassandra DB is up and running?

Comment: This might help: [How to check that Cassandra is ready](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48034869/3776858)

Comment: @Cytuus this one Doesn't help because  it constantly check if db is online (which is not iand it never will be i guess)

Answer (score 0):

Having `CMD` and then `RUN` will not work as they are executed at different lifecycles.

One ways is to have a custom entrypoint, that will start Cassandra in the background, wait for it's getting online, apply the schema change, and wait indefinitely, or until `SIGTERM` (waiting for a signal is better, as it allows to shutdown Cassandra clearly).

Another way - pre-initialize the container during build time, something like this:

1. Start Cassandra in background with `RUN`
2. Wait for it's started, and apply schema changes
3. Terminate Cassandra

then, just normal `cassandra -f` will work as `CMD` command.

Example of such thing [is available in the DataStax's JIRA for Java driver](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-2736?focusedCommentId=52633), and has link to a gist that have Dockerfile + scripts.