# Cannot connect to Cassandra instance in Docker, getting ConnectionRefusedError

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cassandra, connection-refused

I'm running a cassandra container with the the help of docker. For the below set of configuration I'm trying to run the `script.sh` script which should run after cassandra is up and running. However, the below script keeps logging ConnectionRefusedError(111) error:

```
dd_cassandra  | Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': ConnectionRefusedError(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
dd_cassandra  | Waiting for cassandra-node-1...
```

I used the solution described in [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034869/how-to-check-that-a-cassandra-node-is-ready) to check further execute the script only if cassandra is ready but it runs into an infinite wait.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  dd_cassandra:
    container_name: dd_cassandra
    build:
      context: ./cassandra
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: cassandra:latest
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
```

**cassandra/Dockerfile**

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

COPY script.sh /
RUN chmod +x /script.sh
EXPOSE 9042
CMD ["/script.sh"]
```

**cassandra/script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

while ! cqlsh -e 'describe cluster' ; do
  echo "Waiting for cassandra-node-1...";
  sleep 10
done

# some other piece of code that adds runs `cqlsh` command 
# in the cassandra database
```

Comment: Your script runs _instead of_ the `CMD` from the base `cassandra` image, so nothing is actually starting Cassandra.  Usually you'd include something like this as a fragment in an entrypoint script in a client container, not the server proper.

Comment: @DavidMaze The base image for dd_cassandra is `cassandra:latest`. The script should run on top of that image, right?

Comment: The container _only_ runs that script; yes, using the image, but ignoring the `CMD` that's present in the base image's Dockerfile.

Comment: @DavidMaze `Your script runs instead of the CMD from the base cassandra image` - do you mean my script execution has overridded some process which would have started the cassandra in that container?

Comment: @DavidMaze Also, what should be the image inside the client container, if I create one? Also, if I create the client container and run this script as a CMD/ENTRYPOINT inside that client container. Won't the script actually run inside the client instead of the server?

Comment: You should use whatever base image matches your application's implementation language: `node`, `python`, plain `debian` for a compiled language like Go, and so on.  And yes, this script will run in the client, with the specific effect of delaying application startup until the database is ready to use (also see [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y)).  Trying to delay the database container startup until the database is started doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: @DavidMaze But, inside the script there is something more, for eg - a few more `cqlsh` commands which creates tables in the cassandra DB and therefore this should only run on the cassandra container.

Comment: Look for standard patterns for database migrations.  Again, this is something I'd do in the application container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick fix

What you are doing is not exactly correct how containers should be used, but to just fix it you need to add `USER cassandra` to `Dockerfile`

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

COPY script.sh /
RUN chmod +x /script.sh
USER cassandra
EXPOSE 9042
CMD ["/script.sh"]
```

Second change is to add `cassandra` to `script.sh` before `while` (it's needed because when you added your script cassandra service wasn't starting because you have overrided `CMD` [click here and scroll to 'CMD ["cassandra" "-f"]'](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/cassandra/latest/images/sha256-4bb7b4aa45faa63eacaa51a1e4bf50fe839238f7396e428d88d7c2c16cd3abd3?context=explore))

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cassandra
while ! cqlsh -e 'describe cluster' ; do
  echo "Waiting for cassandra-node-1...";
  sleep 2
done
```

This works as I tested.

---

### More appropriate approach

I suggest you doing it a little bit differently. Looking into [How to check that a Cassandra node is ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034869/how-to-check-that-a-cassandra-node-is-ready) someone started `cassandra` container without creating new `Dockerfile` and he just wanted to access it from localhost, probably it was something like this using `docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  dd_cassandra:
    container_name: dd_cassandra
    image: cassandra:latest
    ports:
    - "9042:9042"
```

Then from localhost(not any container) you can access it using `cqlsh localhost 9042 -e 'describe cluster'` if you don't have `cqlsh` installed you can spin-up another container using `docker run -it --rm --network host cassandra:latest bash` and inside type that command

To achieve what you want you can add something like this

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  dd_cassandra:
    container_name: dd_cassandra
    image: cassandra:latest
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"

  cassandra_script:
    build:
      context: ./cassandra
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: cassandra:latest
```

And one more change to `script.sh` we need add host `dd_cassandra`(name of the service/container) instead of using `localhost`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while ! cqlsh dd_cassandra -e 'describe cluster' ; do
  echo "Waiting for cassandra-node-1...";
  sleep 10
done
```

After running `docker-compose up` and waiting around an half minute I got:

```
cassandra-cassandra_script-1  | 
cassandra-cassandra_script-1  | 
cassandra-cassandra_script-1  | Cluster: Test Cluster
cassandra-cassandra_script-1  | Partitioner: Murmur3Partitioner
cassandra-cassandra_script-1  | Snitch: DynamicEndpointSnitch
cassandra-cassandra_script-1  | 
cassandra-cassandra_script-1 exited with code
```

First container `dd_cassandra` is just cassandara service, second container `cassandra_script` has your script.sh in `CMD` so it runs your script, the limitation here is that `Dockerfile` can contain only one `CMD` so if it's used more then once only last occurrence will be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

The Cassandra service doesn't start because you have overridden the default Cassandra startup process when you specified the `CMD` instruction in your Dockerfile (as noted by @David Maze and @zori).

In your script it looks like you're waiting for Cassandra to be operational. Cassandra is considered "ready" when the JVM process starts listening for client connections on the CQL port (default is `9042`). The way to handle this is to perform container `healthchecks`. For example:

```
  healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD-SHELL", "netstat -an | grep -q 9042"]
```

For the rest of your script, it is better to run them in a separate client container that will only start when the Cassandra container is operational using the `depends_on` directive. For example:

```
services:
  cassandra:
    ...
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "netstat -an | grep -q 9042"]
      ...

  cassandra-schema:
    ...
    depends_on:
      cassandra:
        condition: service_healthy
```

For more info, see [the official Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/). Cheers!